# Combining multiple queries into one

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible to join multiple querys in one?

I have 2:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE, cl.updated_at) AS Diff
FROM Table
WHERE Color = 'Red'
```

and

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE, cl.updated_at) AS Diff
FROM Table
WHERE Color = 'Blue'
```

Now i want both in one query

So is try like this:

```
SELECT
(
SELECT DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE, cl.updated_at) AS Diff
FROM Table
WHERE Color = 'Red'
)
(
SELECT DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE, cl.updated_at) AS Diff2
FROM Table
WHERE Color = 'Blue'
)
```

But doenst work :(

Comment: You haven't described the expected output.And I would have thought the answer you accepetd earlier with some trivial modifications might do

Comment: Expected out are 2 different columns

Answer (score 2):

You could use a single query with `IN` operator. This is a short for multiple `OR` conditions:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE, cl.updated_at) AS Diff
FROM Table
WHERE Color IN ( 'Red', 'Blue' )
```

If you really insist on (discouraged) having two queries, then use `UNION ALL` to combine them:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE, cl.updated_at) AS Diff
FROM Table
WHERE Color = 'Red'
UNION ALL -- does not remove duplicates from output
SELECT DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE, cl.updated_at) AS Diff
FROM Table
WHERE Color = 'Blue'
```

If you want to remove duplicates use `UNION` instead of `UNION ALL`.

---

If you need result in different columns as mentioned in a comment then use a `CASE` statement for that. I really don't see a reason for this though.

```
SELECT 
  CASE WHEN Color = 'Red' THEN DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE, cl.updated_at) END AS Diff,
  CASE WHEN Color = 'Blue' THEN DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE, cl.updated_at) END AS Diff2,
FROM Table
WHERE Color IN ( 'Red', 'Blue' )
```

And for second approach:

```
SELECT
  CASE WHEN Color = 'Red'  THEN Diff END AS Diff,
  CASE WHEN Color = 'Blue' THEN Diff END AS Diff2
FROM (
  SELECT Color, DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE, cl.updated_at) AS Diff
  FROM Table
  WHERE Color = 'Red'
  UNION ALL -- does not remove duplicates from output
  SELECT Color, DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE, cl.updated_at) AS Diff
  FROM Table
  WHERE Color = 'Blue'
) t
```

Comment: It would also be useful to add `Color` to columns in `SELECT`, so we know which difference relates to which color.

Comment: Thanks for typo correction. Sure, definitely, I just don't see it in OP's query but normally that would be wise, depending on where you want to use that later.

Comment: I should have said, that i have oversimplyfied this WHERE, in my case its pretty complex and i also need 2 diffrent columns as output

Comment: Updated my answer. If that's not what you need, then your question is unclear.

Comment: Im sorry i try to be more specific. i need a way to easy put my 2 query together, because the are both very long and complex and i have simplyfied my example. case when might work, but i would need a week to recode this...

Comment: Without providing sample data and results there's not much we can help with more than we already did.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it just updating the `where` in this situation?

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE, cl.updated_at) AS Diff FROM Table WHERE Color = 'Blue' OR Color = 'red'
```

And yes you can use an INNER JOIN or UNION, but for this example, that wouldn't be useful.

Comment: This will return 0 rows. Color can't be Blue and Red at the same time :-)

Comment: That's correct! I should use the OR statement, thanks I will update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the UNION operator to Join your two queries. 
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp

Answer (score 0):

If your output column is same in all your query then you can use `UNION / UNION ALL` like below:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE, cl.updated_at) AS Diff
FROM Table
WHERE Color = 'Red'

UNION

SELECT DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE, cl.updated_at) AS Diff
FROM Table
WHERE Color = 'Blue'
```

Comment: I need 2 differnt columns

Comment: Why you want 2 different columns? You can include a column for colors.

Comment: Because its for 2 different statistics and my example is simplified  ;)

Comment: Then add sample data, expected result, because it's unclear.

Answer (score 0):

If you can live with the values in different rows, then just do:

```
SELECT Color, DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE, cl.updated_at) AS Diff
FROM Table
WHERE Color IN ('Red', 'Blue');
```

I added `Color` to the `SELECT` so you can distinguish the rows.

If the subqueries return one value, then you are simply missing a comma:

```
SELECT (SELECT DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE, cl.updated_at) AS Diff
        FROM Table
        WHERE Color = 'Red'
       ),
       (SELECT DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE, cl.updated_at) AS Diff2
        FROM Table
        WHERE Color = 'Blue'
       );
```

If the subqueries return multiple rows, then you need to explain the result set you want.

EDIT:

If you want the values to line up in two different columns, then you can to do something like this:

```
select max(diff_red) as diff_red, max(diff_blue) as diff_blue
from ((select (@rnr := @rnr + 1) as rn, 
              DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE, cl.updated_at) AS Diff_red,
              NULL AS Diff_blue
       from t cross join
            (select @rnr := 0) params
       where color = 'Red'
      ) union all
      (select (@rnb := @rnb + 1) as rn, 
              NULL AS Diff_red,
              DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE, cl.updated_at) AS Diff_blue
       from t cross join
            (select @rnrb:= 0) params
       where color = 'Blue'
      )
     ) rb
group by rn;
```

Comment: I just thought this would fix it, but i still get Error 1242 (Subquery returns more than 1 row), could this be because im joining multiple tables in each? (same for each)

Comment: @Intercept0r . . . As the comments requested, you should provide *sample data* and *desired results*.  We cannot read your mind about what your data looks like.  I edited the answer with what you presumably need.